# Creating a new map frame: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-9.3

I am trying to create a new map frame in the PageLayout Control. But I got the error:  **Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component** at the method AddElement.

Please see below codes:

```
                    IEnvelope envelope = new EnvelopeClass();
                    envelope.PutCoords(Upper_LeftX, Upper_LeftY - _Height, Upper_LeftX + _Width,
                        Upper_LeftY);

                    IMap map = new MapClass();

                    IMapFrame mapFrame = new MapFrameClass();
                    mapFrame.Map = map;
                    IElement mapElement = mapFrame as IElement;
                    mapElement.Geometry = envelope;

                    pageControl.ActiveView.GraphicsContainer.AddElement(mapElement  , 0); // throw error
                    pageControl.ActiveView.FocusMap = mapFrame.Map;
                    pageControl.ActiveView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphics, null, null);
```

Do you know why ?

Thanks and regards,

Tai

Comment: The above error only happen when the pageControl.ActiveView.FocusMap (MapFrame) is being selected

Comment: Are there anyone know how to fix it ?